# nest : The term 'nest' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: nestjs

nest : The term 'nest' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- nest --v
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nest:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEk0o.png)
  ```

i tried it all idk about the PATH the CODE . dont work too

Comment: How did you install `nest` (`npm i -g @nestjs/cli`?). Did you restart your terminal after install?